# issue with cross_validation in pandas_ml

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to complete cross validation with `pandas_ml` library

```
df = pdml.ModelFrame(features, target)
estimators = {'SVM: SVR': df.svm.SVR(),
              'SVM: LinearSVR': df.svm.LinearSVR()}

for label, estimator in estimators.iteritems():
    scores = df.cross_validation.cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, cv=7, scoring='accuracy')
    print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label))
```

However, I got unexpected error

> raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
>
> ValueError: continuous is not supported

Any tricks here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score) metric is for scoring classification models only. It measures the fraction of correct predictions. Instead of what fraction of your predictions are correct, in regression what you want to know is how far away from the correct answer your predictions are  - it's unlikely that any of them will be *exactly* correct so that's not a meaningful metric.

[Regression metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) include `r2`, `mean_squared_error`, `mean_absolute_error`, etc.

You could use something like:

```
scores = df.cross_validation.cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, cv=7, scoring='r2')
```

Comment: Are there any others approaches for regression models?

Comment: http://blog.datadive.net/selecting-good-features-part-i-univariate-selection/ - I see that `cross_val_score` was used with `RandomForestRegressor`

Comment: That's using the `r2` scoring metric. There's no problem using `cross_val_score`, you just need to use an appropriate scoring metric.